# "Could not receive a message from the daemon" error while trying to run a Flutter app in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I was developing a Flutter app using Visual Studio Code and the Android emulator would not respond when trying to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved when I turned off my mobile hotspot. I thought this could help someone